# How to Label Multiple Authors with Same Description

Tags: footnotes, author

I am trying figure out how to have two authors share a footnote symbol and description. I have a template to work with, but am not very good at modifying .sty or .cls files and cannot figure out how to get thanksibid, footnote, or footnotemark to work with it.

The below link contains all the Latex files. Any help on how to get author 1 and author 2 to share a symbol (in this case an *) and only have the symbol once at the bottom would be much appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nt5mhrnzewp45w/latex_test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that demonstrates your problem. This should be a minimal piece of compliable code -- it is much easier for people to help you, and hence much more likely that some one will, if you provide some working code to start from. Making code available via an external link is not very useful because these links may become inactive in the future, rendering your question meaningless.